# What joins are available in Informix 9.2?

Tags: query, join, informix

I'm testing some queries with an old version of Informix (9.2.1) and can't seem to execute even the most basic queries containing `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Tried several variations (`RIGHT JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN` or just `OUTER`), but without any success. `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` work fine.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for outer/right joins in older versions of Informix, or are these joins just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, at least an outer join works just with different syntax: just using `OUTER` with a comma after the first table and a `WHERE` instead of an `ON`.

Edited to add an example from http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls679.htm

```
SELECT c.customer_num, c.lname, o.order_num FROM customer c, 
   OUTER orders o WHERE c.customer_num = o.customer_num
```

Comment: Sorry to ask and answer the question so quickly, wasn't expecting my colleague to know the answer.